# I want to define an array based on condition from two other arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Say I have 2 arrays

```
X = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,])
Y = np.array([6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,])
```

and I want to define an array that takes a value of say 1 wherever X < 3 or Y = 9 and takes a value of 0 everywhere else. I used

```
Z=[1 if i < 3 or j==9 else 0 for i in X and j in Y]
print(Z)
```

I expect an array that looks like

```
[1,1,0,1,0]
```

but I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
np.where((X < 3) | (Y == 9) , 1, 0)
```

Comment: Oh maaaan, i did `where` but i just missed the parenthesis of each condition for the or statement, gave me an error, so i use `logical_or`!!!

Comment: Yeah, the need of parenthesis is a result of operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate over `X` and `Y` in pairs:

```
Z=[1 if i < 3 or j==9 else 0 for i, j in zip(X, Y)]
```

`Z` becomes:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.logical_or`, much more numpy-ish, much faster:

```
print(np.logical_or(X<3,Y==9).astype(int).tolist())
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I recommend this because it's fast.